# What would be the one word to describe this person?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

A person who is silly, outspoken and not following the code of conduct and from a high class city.

Comment: Silly in what way? What is "the code of conduct"? What do you mean by "high class city"?

Comment: For example: Silly- judging without thinking, speaking without sense.                                                                                                         No Code of conduct : Speaking without giving much respect or without knowing the gravity of the situation.                                                                                                      High class: Rich but not royal or from  a family, who concentrates on making money without looking after their children much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally like the world **recalcitrant** as it sounds fancy and is often associated with money. Some examples are the following articles: http://www.mondaq.com/unitedstates/x/667738/tax+authorities/A+Day+of+Reckoning+for+Recalcitrant+Taxpayers
http://www.todayonline.com/singapore/recalcitrant-cigarette-smuggler-gets-40-months-jail-s87m-fine
https://citifmonline.com/2018/02/05/govt-moves-stop-valued-gold-exports/

There are more articles out there, but what I'm basically saying is this word is defined as "resisting authority or control; not obedient or compliant; refractory." by dictionary.com, but it is commonly associated with money and could be used to describe such a person you are talking about. Here is an example sentence:

> Every time we walk in the clothing store, we see these recalcitrant, rich teenagers messing around with the placement of the items in the store.

Answer (score 0):

The below are certainly words that embody most of the characteristics you have asked about in your updated question.

In the situation you described, I would say "spoiled, socially inept or repugnant, and/or cretinous  rich kids." The below are other 'favorites' of mine.

1. **spoiled**
2. **socially inept or repugnant**
3. **cretinous**
4. uncontrolled
5. unruly
6. defiant
7. disorderly
8. insubordinate
9. mischievous
10. unrestrained